# `window.gapi` of gmail javascript librarry not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail

I have used this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login` library to integrate google login in my react application.

But I am fetching error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined` error.

when I check error I found that `window.gapi` is undefined.

It looks like when my content.js file initialize at that time `window.gapi` is undefined.

here are some screenshots of my code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to implement Google login in Chrome extension where access limited to the window object.

There is an example of how to get full access to window object
https://gist.github.com/devjin0617/3e8d72d94c1b9e69690717a219644c7a

Unfortunately, this did not help me and I implemented solution via `chrome.identify` api

Another option is to use Google oauth sdk and implement from scratch